# Return Checkmark after using UISearchBar - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisearchbar, checkmark

I've created a UISearchBar App using this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift). Everything works fine, the cells are configured correctly, and I am able to search by username.

Now I am trying to add a (checkmark ✔︎) to each cell, allowing me to (select ✔︎) multiple users in a list.

The functionality works fine, but when I search the list, (select ✔︎) a user, and return to the main tableview, the user DOES NOT remain selected and vice-versa.

**How can I (checkmark ✔︎) multiple users and maintain that checkmark before or after I use the UISearchBar?**

```
class InviteViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

  var allFriends = [Friend]()
  var filteredFriends = [Friend]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      ###Call to get all Friends
      getFriends()

  }

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
          return self.filteredFriends.count
      } else {
          return self.allFriends.count
      }
  }

  var selectedFriendIndex:Int? = nil

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

      var friend : Friend

      if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
          friend = filteredFriends[indexPath.row]
      } else {
          friend = allFriends[indexPath.row]
      }

      ###Configure the cell
      cell.textLabel!.text = friend.username
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

      if (indexPath.row == selectedFriendIndex) {
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
      } else {
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
      }

      return cell
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

      selectedFriendIndex = indexPath.row
      let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

      if let index = selectedFriendIndex {
          if (cell?.accessoryType == .Checkmark) {
              cell!.accessoryType = .None            
          } else {
              cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
          }
      }
  }

  func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
      self.filteredFriends = self.allFriends.filter({( friend : Friend) -> Bool in
        var usernameMatch = (scope == "All") || (friend.username == scope)
        var stringMatch = friend.username.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText.lowercaseString)
        return usernameMatch && (stringMatch != nil)
      })
  }

  func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
      self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
      return true
  }

  func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
      self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text)
      return true
  }

  func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, willHideSearchResultsTableView tableView: UITableView) {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of what friends are selected in (an array in) your model.

You could add a Bool for each friend, indicating whether they are selected.

This will preserve the selection information when you search and return.

Comment: How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a Bool variable to your object and set it to true or false.

```
 contact.addToGroup = false
```

Swift 3 example:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]

        if (cell.accessoryType == .checkmark) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            contact.addToGroup = false
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            contact.addToGroup = true
        }

    }

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: how do you make the `contact.addToGroup` ? @Nick